# Does the direction of the Referee's gaze affect chances of catching fouls?

Tags: blood-bowl-legendary-edition

The ref typically follows the ball around, and he tends to face the direction of the ball.  If I commit a foul when he's looking away from the body, does that lower the chance of him not catching the foul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say no because technically it's just a dice roll. Look on the rolls tab from the chat window to see them. If there is some modificator it will appear.

Comment: I'll take a look next time I try one (after I get home)

Comment: This is correct. The referee running around in the field is purely a cosmetic one. The dice are the true referees. Basicly two dice are thrown every time you foul, to see if you get past the armor value. If those dice also happen to be doubles, you get caught.